# Panel that supports explicitly setting its headers and has itemtemplateselector property

Tags: wpf, panel

In WPF, I want to show records from a collection in a grid like view. I want to be able to explicitly set the headers of columns. Also I want to use itemtemplateselector property because each object should be displayed differently based on a property value. I have a custom DataTemplateSelector class which gives the correct DataTemplate(whether it contains a textbox or not) by checking a property of the object. Is there a control such that I can explicitly set its headers and itemtemplateselector property. If there isn't such a control, is there a way to achieve the same effect using existing controls? I can create a custom control that has a stackpanel for headers and a itemscontrol for displaying the items but I don't want to deal with all of the alignment issues.

Comment: what's wrong with the standard datagrid so?

Comment: How can I set its column headers explicitly? For example, one column contains checkboxes for each record and its header should be empty.

Comment: are you using AutoGenerateColumns? If you create columns in design time just keep Header empty.

Comment: Can you post sample xaml code that uses itemtemplate of datagrid and sets the headers to specific text? I don't know which header property you are talking about.

Comment: I presume it's a grid control, i.e. it has rows and columns, correct?

Comment: Thanks for the replies but I solved the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by using GridViewHeaderRowPresenter and ItemsControl as described [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823204/wpf-listview-gridview-swaping-item-template)